# Why Multiprocessing is taking more time than sequential processing?

Tags: python

The below code is taking around 15 seconds to get the result. But when I run a it sequentially it
only takes around 11 seconds. What can be the reason for this ?

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
def square(x):
    # print(os.getpid())
    return x*x

if __name__=='__main__':

    start_time = time.time()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    r = range(100000000)
    p1 = p.map(square,r)
    end_time = time.time()
    print('time_taken::',end_time-start_time)
```

Sequential code

```
start_time = time.time()
d = list(map(square,range(100000000)))
end_time = time.time()
```

Comment: Because the multiprocessing overhead costs more than any potential benefits from the multiprocessing

Comment: Not all "simple" cases can be usefully parallelized. This is one of those cases where sequential processing is more time-efficient.

Comment: To be more explicit about what the others have already written.  Multiprocessing involves sending the arguments to another process, having that process perform the calculating, and sending the result back.  Multiprocessing doesn't help if the cost of sending the arguments and getting the results is more expensive than just doing the operation.

Comment: If [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70643047/17850902) answered your question, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your code example, there are two important factors which influence runtime performance gains achievable by parallelization:

First, you have to take the administrative overhead into account. This means, that spawning new processes is rather expensive in comparison to simple arithmetic operations. Therefore, you gain performance, when the computation's complexity exceeds a certain threshold. Which was not the case in your example above.

Secondly, you have to think of a "clever way" of splitting your computation into parts which could be independently executed. In the given code example,  you can optimize the chunks you pass to the worker processes created by `multiprocessing.Pool`, so that each process has a self contained package of computations to perform.

E.g., this could be accomplished with the following modifications of your code:

```py
def square(x):
    return x ** 2


def square_chunk(i, j):
    return list(map(square, range(i, j)))


def calculate_in_parallel(n, c=4):
    """Calculates a list of squares in a parallelized manner"""
    result = []
    step = math.ceil(n / c)

    with Pool(c) as p:
        partial_results = p.starmap(
            square_chunk, [(i, min(i + step, n)) for i in range(0, n, step)]
        )

        for res in partial_results:
            result += res

    return result
```

*Please note, that I used the operation `x**2` (instead of the heavily optimized `x*x`) to increase the load and underline resulting runtime differences.*

Here, the `Pool`'s [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)-function is used which unpacks arguments of the passed tuples. Using it, we can effectively pass more than one argument to the mapped function. Furthermore, we distribute the workload evenly to the amount of available cores. On each core the range of numbers between `(i, min(i + step, n))` is calculated, whereas the `step` denotes the chunksize, calculated as the maximum_number divided by the count of CPU.

By running the code with different parametrizations, one can clearly see, that the performance gain increases when the maximum number (denoted `n`) increases. As expected, when more cores are used in parallel the runtime is reduced as well.

[image: Comparison of runtime performance]
**Edit:**
As @KellyBundy pointed out, parallelism (especially) shines, when you minimize not only the input to the worker processes but the output as well. Performing several measurements calculating the sum of the squared numbers (`sum(map(square, range(i, j)))`) instead of returning (and concatenating) lists, showed an even larger increase in runtime performance as the following figure illustrates.

[image]

Comment: Is your graph correctly labeled? It looks like runtime is larger with 4 cores than sequentially.

Comment: I corrected the figure, @VictorEijkhout!

Comment: We overlapped. Say, your runtimes are 10 times faster than the OP, even for sequential. Any explanation? Also: this is a numerical calculation so I would use NumPy arrays rather than python lists. I'll bet that gives you another factor of 10.

Comment: Could you add code and graph for *sum* of squares instead of *list* of squares? I.e., don't just minimize the *input* for the processes but also their *output*. I think that would then be a good example for something where parallelization is really appropriate, and I'd like to see whether that indeed gives an almost 4x and 8x speedup.

Comment: The 10 times faster runtimes have a simple explanation, as you can see from the value labels on the x-axis I stopped at 10_000_000, because of the fact, that I took the mean of multiple runs and wanted to save some time. Should have clarified that, @VictorEijkhout

Regarding the hint on NumPy: I tested the code and created `np.array()`s instead of lists and did not see clear performance benefits.

Comment: This is a very good point, @KellyBundy
I added a figure for the calculation fo the sum of the square numbers and one can see the large performance benefit, that you expected.

Comment: @jgru Thanks. Not actually as good as I had expected, though. Looks like parallel is only 3x faster. I really hoped it would get almost 4x and 8x faster. How many cores do you actually have?

Comment: @KellyBundy the machine running the tests has a i7-9850h with 12 cores available and did not run any resource intensive application during the time of test.